# How do I get this program to open the last modified date workbook by the date in the name

Tags: excel, vba

My files are all named **MyFile053017.xls** and **myfile052517.xls**.

I am trying to grab the date in the name and use that as the last modified date, just in case of an instance where someone opens and saves one of the workbooks

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    
    'Specify the path to the folder
    MyPath = "M:\Users\Dan\Access\DiscontinueQuery\DiscontinueQuerySave\"
    
    'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
    'Get the first Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    
    'If no files were found, exit the sub
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    
        'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        
        'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
        'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        
        'Get the next Excel file from the folder
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Open the latest file
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you get in the Immediate window when you add `debug.print MyFile & " - " & LMD` after `LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)` ?

Comment: Just to make sure... Are you saying that any file named `MyFile053017.xls` must always be newer than another one named `myfile052517.xls`? Besides, if the actual `last modification dates` matche those names, then yes the first one is the "latest".

Comment: still gave me oldest file

Comment: Well i thought this program was analyzing the workbooks date within the name not the actual date modified. So when i saved one and copied it down with different dates it wouldn't work like that. I was trying to test to make sure it was finalized before I moved onto the next vba. Thank you A.S.H XD

Comment: Now im going forward with getting that file to open into the current workbook as a sheet with the name of the workbook, Then im going to compare changes from sheet to sheet with a new sheet containing the changes.. Got a lot of ways togo.

Comment: Seems, you want to open first file based on the date included in its name, but not on time of its creation. Am i right?

Comment: Correct, just in case someone opens it and saves it. I am also trying to figure out how i get the second to last "last modified workbook", so i can compare the two most recent.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only look at the filenames to determine the "latest" file, then instead of calling `FileDateTime` on the full path, call the function below on the filename only.

You will need to make some adjustments of your file names aren't exactly as shown in your question.

```
'MyFile053017.xls >> 5/30/2017
Function NewFileDateTime(sFile As String)
    NewFileDateTime = DateSerial(2000 + Mid(sFile, 11, 2), _
                                        Mid(sFile, 7, 2), _
                                        Mid(sFile, 9, 2))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add another solution by using regular expression. Tim's solution is more concise, but regular expression avoids calculation the positions of numbers (in case if the file name will change in the future). The pattern simply searches for six numbers and make groups of them feeding them to `DateSerial` function:

```vb
Function FileDateTime(file_name$)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})"
        With .Execute(file_name)(0)
            FileDateTime = DateSerial(2000 + .SubMatches(2), .SubMatches(0), .SubMatches(1))
        End With
    End With
End Function
```